# Java saving variable from subclass in superclass

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class, super

I am trying to design a Java program based on the following UML class diagram for an assignment and I am stuck on getting a `name` and `xPosition` for the create method of the `House` and `ApartmentBuilding` classes and storing it in its parent class (`Building`) and interface (`Drawable`).

[image]

###### *Drawable*:

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;



 interface Drawable {

   void draw(GraphicsContext canvas);

   public double getXPosition();
   
}
```

###### *Building*:

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

public class Building implements Drawable {


    private final String name;

    private final double xPosition;

        public Building(){

            this.name = " ";
            this.xPosition = 0.0;

    }

    public Building(String name, double xPosition){

            this.name = name;
            this.xPosition = xPosition;
    }




    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }


    public void draw(GraphicsContext canvas) {

    }


    public double getXPosition() {
        return xPosition;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
            return "Type... Building:  " + "name= " + name + ", xPosition= " + xPosition + "\n";}
    }
```

###### *House*:

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class House extends Building implements Dwelling  {

    int bedrooms;
    int occupants;

    House(int bedrooms, int occupants){
        this.bedrooms = bedrooms;
        this.occupants = occupants;
    }
    public static House create() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        House a;


        System.out.println("Enter name of the House: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter XPosition of the House: ");
        int xPosition = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of bedrooms: ");
        int bedrooms = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of occupants: ");
        int occupants = scan.nextInt();

        a = new House(bedrooms, occupants);


        return a;

    }
    public void draw(GraphicsContext canvas){


    }



    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "House: " + "bedrooms= " + bedrooms + " occupants= " + occupants + "\n" + super.toString();
    }


    @Override
    public int getNumberOfOccupants() {
        return occupants;
    }
}
```

###### *ApartmentBuilding*:

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ApartmentBuilding extends HighRise implements Dwelling{

    int occupantsPerFloor;
    int numberOfFloors;

    ApartmentBuilding(int numberOfFloors, int occupantsPerFloor){
        this.occupantsPerFloor = occupantsPerFloor;
        this.numberOfFloors = numberOfFloors;

    }

    public static ApartmentBuilding create() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ApartmentBuilding a;


        System.out.println("Enter name of the Apartment Building: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter XPosition of the Apartment Building: ");
        int xPosition = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of floors: ");
        int numberOfFloors = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of occupants per floor: ");
        int occupantsPerFloor = scan.nextInt();

        a = new ApartmentBuilding(numberOfFloors, occupantsPerFloor);


        return a;
    }


    public void draw(GraphicsContext canvas){

    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){

        return "Apartment Building: " + "occupantsPerFloor= " + occupantsPerFloor + "\n" + super.toString() + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumberOfOccupants() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am new at programming and trying my best to learn but I am getting stuck on this, unfortunately.

Comment: Your constructor for House could take all four parameters (including name and XPOsition) as read in the `create` then in the constrcutor call `super(name, xPosition)`

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
private final String name;
private final double xPosition;

public Building(){
    this.name = " ";
    this.xPosition = 0.0;
}
```

is likely messing things up for you. Since `name` and `xPosition` are declared `final`, giving `Building` a default constructor, one that takes no parameters and that sets `name` and `xPosition` to default (and useless) values, means that unless you take care to make sure that the subclasses explicitly call the other super constructor, the one that does require parameters and that sets the values for the above fields to a reasonable value, the above fields will prove useless to you.

I suggest that you do away with the default constructor above and instead allow Building to only have one constructor, the one that requires a `String` and a `double` parameter:

```
public Building(String name, double xPosition){
    this.name = name;
    this.xPosition = xPosition;
}
```

and then be sure that child classes call this super constructor in their own constructor, passing in appropriate values.

e.g.,

```
public class House extends Building implements Dwelling  {
    private int bedrooms;
    private int occupants;

    House(String name, double xPosition, int bedrooms, int occupants) {
        super(name, xPosition);
        this.bedrooms = bedrooms;
        this.occupants = occupants;
    }
```

This way you can force `House` instances to fill the appropriate super class fields, and these values are available to `House` instances and appropriately returned when `.getName()` or `.getXPosition()` is called on `House` instances.